# Python tkinter textvariable in label widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a variable called 'localtime2' within my def in the code and then have a label which says 'textvariable=localtime2.' the problem is that it does not display the information about the variable.

```
localtime2 = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
tk.Label(roots, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=localtime2, bd=16, anchor="w").grid(row=2, column=0)
```

This is all I have in the code about this variable and it is not coming up with any error in the terminal. It just doesnt show at all.

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: Would it be ok if i put on a github post and linked

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SJones72413/f4ef37cacdf49bd9a7d4a890bcfb7d75 link for entire code

Comment: The variable might not be able to keep up as the time is always moving, maybe you could put in a `while True:` loop?

Comment: I have used time previously as i have 2 gui's in the code and have done the exact same thing in the other one however it just doesnt work in this gui. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** The solution to the original post was using `text=localtime2.get()` instead of `textvariable=localtime2` in the label widget (*for some strange reason*). However, my original answer is still correct as tkinter variables should be used and so I will keep it up.

---

You must use tkinter variables in tkinter widgets and not normal python variables. Tkinter variables are slightly different to normal variables and must first be defined as a specific data type. For example, a variable which contains a string must be first created like so:

```
string_variable = tk.StringVar()
```

likewise a boolean would be created like so:

```
boolean_variable = tk.BooleanVar()
```

Read [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) for more information on tkinter variables.

These variables are in fact classes so in order to set them use must call the `.set()` method. Therefore to set a tkinter String variable to *"a string"* you would use the following code:

```
string_variable = tk.StringVar() # Create the variable 
string_variable.set("a string") # Set the value of the variable
```

---

Thus to fix your code you need to make `localtime2` a tkinter variable and set it to the time using the `.set()` method.

Example:

```
localtime2 = tk.StringVar() # Create the localtime2 string variable
localtime2.set(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))) # Set the variable
tk.Label(roots, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=localtime2, bd=16, anchor="w").grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Comment: I really do appreciate the time you have taken do do this however it has not fixed the problem. It still doesnt have a error message also it just does not show still.

Comment: May I see the rest of the code. The github link you provided in the comments brings me to a 404 page (page not found)

Comment: I am quite new to python so it might be a complete  and utter mess. Its not that I do it on purpose i just havent learnt the ways to avoid it yet.

Comment: @Jsam This is very odd. It seams that the label will not not work using the `textvariable` field. However it seemed to display when i used the `text` field instead. Use this code instead `text=localtime2.get()` in your Label widget that uses the localtime2 variable and see if that works.

Comment: @Jsam Glad to help! Although I have no idea why that works and not the other way. ;)

Comment: using `text` will work but that will defeat the purpose of initially declaring it as tkinter variable

Comment: @swayamraina Yes that is true, you could use a normal python variable. But for some reason using `textvariable` doesn't work. The OP used `textvariable` so I assumed that the use of a normal variable was the problem but I'm not sure anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever there is a change in a **tkinter variable**, the update is automatically reflected everywhere. Because of this property you cannot use a normal python variable here.
Try using `StringVar()` and then setting the variable content using `set()`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time. I have just tried this as the person above has mentioned however it has not seemed to change anything. Thank you